# If $f(x,y)=\int^x_y \cos(t^2)\,dt$, find the first partial derivatives of the function

Tags: partial-derivative

Problem: If $f(x,y)=\int^x_y \cos(t^2) \, dt$, find the first partial derivatives of the function.

My thoughts: By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, I know that $f_x=\cos(x^2)$, since $y$ is just treated as  a constant.

But what about $f_y$? Am I right in assuming that it would be $-\cos(x^2)$, since $\int^x_a f(t) \, dt=-\int^a_x f(t) \, dt$? Or are things more complicated than that?

Comment: It is just that.

Comment: Not quite... be careful about which variable is which.

Comment: @Micah Thanks, good catch- did you mean it should be $-cos(y^2)$ instead of $-cos(x^2)$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I would think of this (because it works better in more complicated situations where the limits are functions of $x$ and $y$) is to let $g$ be an antiderivative of $t \mapsto \cos t^2$. Then the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus tells us that
$$
f(x,y)=g(x)-g(y)
$$
which is easy to take partial derivatives of when you remember that $g'(t)=\cos t^2$.

But your way works too (except for the issue I mentioned in the comments).

Comment: When I try doing it this way for $f_x$, I get $cos(x^2)-g(y)$, but how do we know that $g(y)$ is 0?

Comment: $g(y)$ is independent of $x$, so $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} g(y)=0$.

Comment: Oops, I had a brain fart there- it all makes sense now. Thanks!